# YamlDotNet Convertir de YAML a JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json, yaml

Necesito ayuda cuando intento convertir un yaml a json, está pasando todas las propiedades a la cadena y no reconoce los campos bool o integer.

Estoy usando la biblioteca YamlDotNet, en c #. Si alguien me puede ayudar lo agradecería.

```
public static string ConvertirYamlAJson(TextReader yml)
{
    var deserializer = new DeserializerBuilder().Build(); 
    var yamlObject = deserializer.Deserialize(yml); 
    var serializer = new SerializerBuilder().JsonCompatible().Build(); 
    string json = serializer.Serialize(yamlObject); 
    return json;
}
```

Comment: Deberia publicar tambien: 1. El texto que esta llegando a traves de `TextReader yml` 2. El json de salida deseado

Comment: Gracias ya se soluciono https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70095860/yamldotnet-convert-yaml-to-json-in-c-sharp/70097714#70097714